Markdown editor for Windows that can run a shell command on save / on button click
I need a text editor with the following attributes:

Must run on Microsoft Windows
Must be gratis, i.e. free in terms of price
Preferrably free/libre/open-source
Must allow syntax-highlighting, or otherwise provide support for Markdown files
Must have an editing experience that an average computer user would expect, i.e. not Vim/Emacs in a near-default configuration
Must have one of the following:

A way to register a shell command to execute when the Markdown file is saved
A way to register a shell command to a button, that is executed when the button is pressed


Preferably not a web app (e.g. VS Code)

I've tried to use VS Code but I am incapable of understanding tasks.json and other relevant configuration files.
I've also considered using GNU Emacs with after-save-hook and cua-mode, though that also seems to be overkill, and the user might still be confused if they enter a menu like M-x.
(The command I would like to run is pandoc --slide-level=2 -t beamer -o basename.pdf -f markdown basename.md.)

Hello, I mean, VSCode is what instantly jumps to mind, but if you want to avoid Electron, then Sublime Text is basically VSCode written in C++/Python in terms of available plugins, which definitely cover what you wrote.
